# Process Builder - Add Minutes,Hours to Event End Date

Tags: formula, process-builder, datetime, date, event

I want to make the Event End Date as `NOW()+60 Mins` in process builder while creating a new Event record. But It is adding 60 DAYS even though Event End date is date/time field.

[image]

How do I add minutes **directly** to the current time.

I want to add `NOW()+ 15 mins`, `Now()+60 Mins` (i.e., 1 Hour). Any ideas?

Comment: can you try adding 1/24 for 1 hour?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the Formula like

```
Now() + (60/24/60)
```

Give your required minutes in first 60.

If you want for 10 minutes to be added, Give like

`Now() + (10/24/60)`

Then you will get the 60 minutes added to the Present Time

Hope this might helps....